Sphere coordinates display discontinuous images
As the title says, the program uses threejs.
Code below:
const mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
const pointer = new THREE.Vector2();
window.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove );
function onMouseMove(ev) {
  mouse.x = ev.clientX / window.innerWidth;
  mouse.y = ev.clientY / window.innerHeight;
  ev.preventDefault();
  pointer.x = (ev.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  pointer.y = -(ev.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  lightHandle()
  operate()
  render()
  stats.update()
}

function render() {
  camera.position.x = observer.x + v.x
  camera.position.y = observer.y + v.y
  camera.position.z = observer.z + v.z
  camera.lookAt(observer)
  renderer.render(scene, camera)
}

function operate() {
  omega.x = .5 * Math.PI * (-mouse.x + .5)
  omega.y = .5 * Math.PI * (mouse.y - .5)
  omega.z = .5 * Math.PI * (mouse.x - .5)
  v.x = Math.cos(theta.y + omega.y) * Math.sin(theta.x + omega.x) * .5
  v.y = Math.sin(theta.y + omega.y) * .5
  v.z = Math.cos(theta.y + omega.y) * Math.cos(theta.x + omega.x) * .5
}

function motion() { 
  theta.x = (theta.x + omega.x * .1) % (2 * Math.PI)
  theta.y = (theta.y + omega.y * .1) % (2 * Math.PI)
  theta.z = (theta.z + omega.z * .1) % (2 * Math.PI)
}

init()
animate()

Mouse movement animation will jump unnaturally like below.
The animation in the video is not continuous
Camera system:

The following video:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fpFu89KlFGR-9zxzq1iqYdk60JPJKkxX/view?usp=sharing
Animation display smooth and natural.

Try interpolating mouse values be lerp method. And BTW add tag Threejs…
